# How to write criterion tests?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to compare the performance of two functions(one based on mutable `vector` and the other on `Data.Set`) The basic idea is to run my function on a randomly generated string of length `1000`

**My question:**

This is the first time ever that I write any bench marking code. So any suggestions or comments are welcome. I feel my code or setup is wrong.

Here's the criterion bench file:

```
import           Control.Monad  (replicateM)
import           Criterion.Main
import           Lib.Happy
import           System.Random  (randomIO)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  str <- replicateM 1000 randomIO :: IO String
  defaultMain [
    bgroup "Compare Data Structure Performance" [
      bench "with Data.Set" $ whnf isUniqueChars2 str
    , bench "with Mutable Vector" $ whnf isUniqueChars2 str
    ]
    ]
```

Here's where library functions are defined(in `Lib/Happy.hs`):

```
isUniqueChars :: String -> Bool
isUniqueChars str =
  runST $ do
    charset <- V.thaw . V.fromList . replicate 128 $ False
    go str charset
  where
    go :: (PrimMonad m) => String
       -> MV.MVector (PrimState m) Bool
       -> m Bool
    go [] _ = return True
    go (x:xs) charset = do
      b <- MV.read charset (ord x)
      if b
        then return False
        else
        do
          MV.write charset (ord x) True
          go xs charset

-- Method 2: Data.Set
-- O(n log n)
isUniqueChars2 :: String -> Bool
isUniqueChars2 str =
  let charset = S.fromList []
  in go str charset
  where
    go [] _ = True
    go (x:xs) charset = if S.member x charset -- O(log n)
      then False
      else go xs (S.insert x charset) -- O(log n)
```

Let me post also my `cabal` file because I feel there's something a little off with it too.

```
cabal-version:       >=1.10

name:                happyhaskell
version:             0.1.0.0
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              me
maintainer:          me@hotmail.fr
build-type:          Simple
extra-source-files:  CHANGELOG.md

executable happyhaskell
  main-is:             Main.hs
  build-depends:       base >=4.14 && <4.15
                     , happyhaskell
  default-language:    Haskell2010

library
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  exposed-modules:     Lib.Happy
  build-depends:       base >=4.14 && <4.15
                     , containers
                     , primitive >= 0.7.1.0
                     , vector

benchmark bench
  default-language:    Haskell2010
  type:                exitcode-stdio-1.0
  main-is:             Bench.hs
  other-modules:       Lib.Happy
  build-depends:       base >=4.14 && <4.15
                     , happyhaskell
                     , criterion
                     , random
                     , containers
                     , primitive >= 0.7.1.0
                     , vector
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I feel there's something wrong with my code but I don't know where

Comment: Well, you have `isUniqueChars2` twice and `isUniqueChars` 0 times. So that could be it. But "I feel there's something wrong" isn't really... specific enough to help with. What observations, specifically, are causing that feeling? What observations did you expect that would not have caused that feeling?